# Is there a data structure that adds a hash table to speed up a binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, hashtable

By hashing the nodes of a binary tree by key, Lookup() and Remove() operations can be reduced from O(logn) to O(1). Does this structure exist? Wouldn't you see a considerable benefit in using something like this?

```
// balanced binary tree node
class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> left;
    Node<T> right;
    Node<T> parent;

    Add(T item) { ... }
    Contains(T item) { ... }
    Delete(T item) { ... }
}

class MyStructure<T> {

    Node<T> tree;
    Dictionary<T, Node<T>> table;

    // O(1) lookup
    bool Contains(T item) {
        return table.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    // faster deletion (O(1) when not rebalancing), because there is no need to search for the node in the tree
    Delete(T item) {
        var node = table[item];
        table.Remove(item);
        node.parent.Remove(item);
    }

    // Add() still O(logN)
    bool Add(T item) {
        table.Add(item);
        tree.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: which operation? how "hashing the nodes" can speed it up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help you to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: Mixing 2 datastructures  (`X`&`Y`) in a side-by-side style (like in your code) will usually yield cost of write operation = `X`'s + `Y`'s.   There is some useful cases like your `Contains()` that worth mixing, but it is not so common.